# How to use push function in fixed length array

Tags: solidity

I write code of fixed size array with 6 index in array ,but array have 5 elements
i need to append only 1 element, i cant use push function

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
contract myArray{
    uint[6] public ipadProPrice=[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500];

    function addToPrice(uint _addToPrice) public{
       ipadProPrice.push(_addToPrice);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't push to a fixed size array because it has been fixed already, and memory has already been allocated to it. If you want to push, you need to use dynamic arrays. Dynamic arrays have no fixed size, can contain numbers, and keep growing. You can push, however, as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
contract myArray{
    uint[] public ipadProPrice =[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500];

    function addToPrice(uint _addToPrice) public{
       ipadProPrice.push(_addToPrice);
    }
}
```